# An Euler problem: How many of these numbers are of the form $a^b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, project-euler

How much numbers can be written in the form $a^b$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers that are between $2$ and $100$?

How can I start this problem? Any hints please?

Thanks!

Comment: A start: I interpret the problem as meaning that you can choose $a$ and $b$ freely from $2$ to $100$, getting some pretty huge numbers.   We can choose $a$ in $99$ ways, and for each choice we can choose $b$ in $99$ ways, total $99^2$. But some numbers are multiple counted, for example $4^2$, $8^2=4^3=2^6$, and so on. If you can deal with the multiple counting, you will have the answer.

Comment: Excellent André!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $2\le a^b\le 100,$ if you let $b=1,2,\cdots$, what kind of condition of $a$ can you get?

Comment: that a is greater than 2?

Comment: Yes, but you can get it. Letting $b=1$ gives you $2\le a\le 100.$ Letting $b=2$ gives you $2\le a^2\le 100$. What do you think?

Comment: a=10 since a^2 so a={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} and b={1,2} we move on to a^3 and so on ... ?

Comment: $2\le a^3\le 100\Rightarrow a=2,3,4$ because $4^3=64\lt 100\lt 5^3=125.$ The number of $a$ you get is getting smaller.

Comment: Yes just as i've done ;) thanks

Comment: You are welcom!